# Repeat loop for foreach loop size in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I want the for loop to be as big as the forech loop. I put a counter and it works well to send values to the action, but in the view, if I have 4 people, it repeats the same. See the picture and you will understand.

[pleas see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlZBH.png)

These are just 4 people and when I send their data to the action, exactly the same 4 are sent, but in the view you see it repeated

See also the code :

```
@{
    int n = 1;
}

<form action="/Home/paySalery" method="post">

    @foreach (var item in Model.ProjectViewModels)
    {
      
        @for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

      
        <tr>
            <td class="tablehead">@item.PersonName</td>
            <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 25px" name="[@i].workDay" /></td>
            <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 30px" name="[@i].AzafeKaryMinet" /></td>
            <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 30px" name="[@i].mamoriatDay" /></td>
            <td><input class="tablehead" type="text" style="width: 60px" name="[@i].haghGhza" /></td>
            <td><input class="tablehead" type="text" style="width: 60px" name="[@i].padash" /></td>
            <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 30px" name="morakhsee" /></td>
            <td><input class="tablehead" type="text" style="width: 60px" name="[@i].porsantForosh" /></td>
            <td><input class="tablehead" type="text" style="width: 60px" name="[@i].SairMzaya" /></td>
            <td><input class="tablehead" type="text" style="width: 60px" name="[@i].KhareedAsForoshghe" /></td>
            <td><input class="tablehead" type="text" style="width: 60px" name="[@i].ghastVam" /></td>
            <td><input class="tablehead" type="text" style="width: 60px" name="[@i].MosaedeNaghdee" /></td>
            <td><input class="tablehead" type="text" style="width: 60px" name="[@i].MosaedeVareezBeHasab" /></td>
            <td><input class="tablehead" type="text" style="width: 60px" name="[@i].SairKosorat" /></td>
            <input class="form-control d-none" type="number" name="[@i].PersonID" value="10" />
            <input class="form-control d-none" type="number" name="[@i].projectID" value="7" />
            <input class="form-control d-none" type="number" name="[@i].hokmID" value="12" />
            <input class="form-control d-none" type="number" name="[@i].month" value="10" />
            <input class="form-control d-none" type="number" name="[@i].yeur" value="1" />

        </tr>

         
        }
        n++;
    }
    <button class="btn btn-success mb-4" type="submit">ثبت حقوق</button>

    </form>
```

As you see, I put a counter, but it does not work properly in View. I want the for loop to rotate to the number of people in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change your code like below:

```
<form action="/Home/paySalery" method="post">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProjectViewModels.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="tablehead">@Model.ProjectViewModels[i].PersonName</td>
            <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 25px" name="[@i].workDay" /></td>
            <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 25px" name="[@i].AzafeKaryMinet" /></td>
         //.....
        </tr>
    }    
    <button class="btn btn-success mb-4" type="submit">ثبت حقوق</button>
</form>
```